# Crossrider setPopup() small width

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, crossrider

My Crossrider plugin users the setPopup() function to make a popup when the browserAction icon is clicked.

The problem is that when I click the icon, the popup is long and thin and unusable.

**Here is a screenshot of what it looks like...**

[image: The tall, thin popup... :(]

**My background.js code:**

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('icons/logo38.gif');
    appAPI.browserAction.setTitle('Click here for iStyla preferences');
    appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({resourcePath:'popup.html'});
});
```

My **popup.html** has a finite minimum width, so I don't know why the popup's width is so small. I am using Firefox 18.0.2.

Please help me to make the popup wider... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the width and height of the popup from within the **popup.html** file.
Simply style the **body** tag with the required *height* and *width* attributes. For example:

```
<body style="height:200px; width:300px;">
...
</body>
```

For more information, see [setPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup).

Comment: Thanks. I set a min-width, but that didn't work. Setting a width worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also control the width and the height of the popup through the api

```
appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({
    resourcePath:'html/popup.html',
    height: 300,
    width: 300
```

});